# Auto resize image

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets, image-resizing

Is there any way to resize image uploaded to server? I have uploaded a image using servlet and JSP. Now I want to resize that image according to fixed ratio.

Is there any API available?

Answer (score 0):

```
Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(scale, scale,
            java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

Comment: FYI You might to take a read of [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

Comment: I am just using getScaledInstance to statically initialize tiny icons, so I never noticed the performance issues. Nice, in-depth article though!

Answer (score -2):

Quoting from http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/

> Graphics2D is providing the image re-size feature as follows :
>
> ```
> BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
> Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
> g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
> g.dispose();
> ```